JTextField not editable directly
I want to have a J(Formatted)TextField that is not directly editable (you can't enter or remove characters).
That said, it would be editable indirectly (I won't say how, but the point is I would programmatically set its value after a certain sequence of events). If I set the field's editable property to false, its L&F would paint the background gray which would strongly imply it's not editable at all. I'd like to avoid that.
To recap, the field should not be editable, no caret, but it should still have a white background. Technically, I could pepper my L&F extension with intanceofs, but that's obviously not what I'd like to do. Ugly listeners that swallow key input — again, it feels like a kludge.
How do you suggest I achieve that?
Java 8, Swing.

better question is: what do you suggest to do? Try, and if it fails, show us your code and the error you get

@Stultuske it's not a debugging question

I don't see the problem. Maybe you could make a sample program, and show the difference. For me the background is white if I disable the field, but the text is gray.

@Cagepi I know. It's a "teach me how" question, which SO is not suited for.

"strongly imply it's not editable at all." But the field is not editable, so this is exactly what you should be doing! The whole point of that appearance is to answer the user's thought "Can I click here to edit?". The fact that other indirect actions may result in a new value is irrelevant.

@BasilBourque well, anyway, that's expected of our app

Isn't field.setDisabledTextColor(new ColorUIResource(Color.BLUE));     field.setBackground(new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK)); (for example) what you need?

You could leave the editable property true but set a custom Document implementation which ignores the standard insert and remove calls, so there is no change through the standard input ſ actions but provide an application specific API for the application specific manipulations.

Here is an example using the UIManager, the thing is my default look and feel doesn't use a disabled background color, maybe yours does.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
public class DisabledWhiteTextField{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    UIManager.put("TextField.inactiveForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLUE));
    UIManager.put("TextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE));

    //This is just for debugging to see what the current LAF recognizes. maybe.
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().forEach( (k, v) ->{
        System.out.println(k + ", " + v );}
    );
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("text");
    JTextField field = new JTextField(40);

    field.setEnabled(false);
    field.setText("what");
    frame.add(new JLabel("below"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JTextField two = new JTextField(40);
    two.setText("ever");
    frame.add(two, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}

This works to set the disabled text to non-gray for me.

After playing around with it a bit, I found the values are different for the different look and feels.
UIManager.put("TextField.disabledBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLUE));
UIManager.put("TextField.inactiveForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.YELLOW));

That lets me see the values for a windows look and feel.

UIManager.put will change the colors for every JTextField created from then on, regardless of whether it is meant to have the functionality Cagepi desires.  Why not just call setForeground and setBackground on the JTextField itself?

@VGR that sounds reasonable. OP seemed to want to set just the disabled colors, and this kinda does that. It illustrates the difficulty of going through the UI manager. Where you get different results for different look and feels. If I am not mistaken though, are the JTextField backgrounds managed a bit differently? As in you have the background and the editor background, so maybe an example would work well.
